# AWK Compare two files and print matching columns with IP addresses

Tags: awk

I don't like asking for help, and for the most part can figure things out; however I cannot get my head around what I am doing incorrect.

There are two files [redacted for obvious reasons]:

First File; Is a list of IPs to "look-up".

**$OUT**

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
111.111.111.111
```

Second File; Is the log file to scan for the IPs and fetch the ClientUID.

**$file**

```
[0513.65] DevNet: Join succeeded: FoObAr playerid=0x0000000000000000
[0522.25] NetComeGo: Close IpNetDriverSteamworks_0 IpNetConnectionSteamworks_2 111.111.111.111:12345
[0522.25] DevOnline: EndRemoteClientAuthSession: ClientAddr: 111.111.111.111:12345, ClientUID: 00000000000000000
[0522.25] DevOnline: EndLocalServerAuthSession: ClientAddr: 111.111.111.111, ClientUID: 00000000000000000
[0522.25] DevOnline: EndLocalServerAuthSession: SessionUID: 4
```

**Desired Output:**

```
ClientAddr: 111.111.111.111 ClientUID: 00000000000000000
```

---

I have tried this:

`awk --posix 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next}{for (i in a){if($4 ~ /^ClientAddr/ && $5 ~ /"^"a[i]/)print $4 $5 $6 $7}}' $OUT $file`

*also*

`awk --posix 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{for (i in a){if($4 ~ /^ClientAddr/ && $5 ~ /"^"a[i]/)print $4 $5 $6 $7}}' $OUT $file`

But it does not work; I have spent the past few days reading and looking up information .... but I just can't get my head around what I have done wrong.



**Full bash script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
OUT=/tmp/scanLog/data.tmp

awk --posix '$2 ~ /^NetComeGo/ && $5 ~ /^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/ {a[$5]++}END{for(i in a)if(a[i] > 100){print i}}' $file >$OUT

awk --posix 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next}{for (i in a){if($4 ~ /^ClientAddr/ && $5 ~ /"^"a[i]/)print $4 $5 $6 $7}}' $OUT $file

rm $OUT
```

---

*I am currently having difficulties with my mental health; I hope that this request for help makes sense.*

---

Comment: Why is there only one row in desired output?

Comment: What output are you getting when you run it? In what way is it incorrect?

Comment: How attached are you to doing this in AWK?  It might be simpler in Perl or Python.

Comment: Perl could be an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you need to check lines in Input_file2 which have same IP address found in Input_file1 + which has `ClientUID` in line and IP address is followed by `:digits` in that line if that is the case then could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]
  next
}
/ClientUID:/ && match($0,/ClientAddr: [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+:[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+12,RLENGTH-12)
  sub(/:.*/,"",val)
  if(val in a){
    print "ClientAddr:",val,$(NF-1),$NF
  }
}
'  Input_file1  Input_file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                              ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                           ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Input_file1 is being read.
  a[$0]                                            ##Creating array a with index current line here.
  next                                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/ClientUID:/ && match($0,/ClientAddr: [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+:[0-9]+/){    ##Checking condition if ClientUID is present in line and ClientAddr with IP addrsss then colon digits are present in current line then do following.
  val=substr($0,RSTART+12,RLENGTH-12)              ##Creating variable val which has sub-string of current line
  sub(/:.*/,"",val)                                ##Substituting from colon to everything till last with NULL in val to get only IP address.
  if(val in a){                                    ##Checking if val is present in a then do following.
    print "ClientAddr:",val,$(NF-1),$NF            ##Printing string ClientAddrthen val then last 2 fields of line here as per shown samples.
  }
}
'  file1 file2                                     ##Mentioning Inpupt_file names here.
```